# How can I make multiple variable value to replace EL expression one by one In Nifi?

Tags: el, apache-nifi

[image]

I just know a single value can replacing EL expression

but idk how the result set replace EL one by one,as picture.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Split one resultset to different ff, then transform each value to sql statement.

Comment: Hi,@daggett Thank you for your prompt reply.I've done this before:`ExecuteSQL->SplitAvro->ConvertAvroToJSON->ExecuteSQL`.But they were transformed to INSERT\U\D type except QUERY statement,when FF passed in `CATJ`.Any other suggestions?TIA

Comment: Please clarify your need. Your 1st sql query returns resultset with column names, then each row you want to convert to sql select but with substituted column name. Then what?

Comment: Sorry @daggett.For Piecing together sql,and then execute them.For example the last processor need execute `select '${column_name}',A_column,B_column  from table`.A/B_columns are constant,and '${column_name}' is variable.Can you give me advice?TY

Comment: SplitAvro - AvroToJson - EvaluateJSONPath (to put dynamic column name into ff attribute) - Replace text (to substitute content with sql query with substituted column name)

Comment: I made it!!!! Niubility！蟹蟹您 @daggettd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @daggett again.ExecuteSql - SplitAvro - AvroToJson - EvaluateJSONPath (to put dynamic column name into ff attribute) - ExecuteSql(to set ${dynamic_column_name} for substituting sql query)